# Unity, getting an error in script C#, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Скорость перемещения")]
    public float speed = 7f;
    
    [Header("Мы на земле?")]
    public bool ground;
    
    [Header("Сила прыжка")]
    public float jumpPower = 200f;
    
    [Header("Скорость бега")]
    public float runSpeed = 15f;
    
    public Rigidbody rb;
    
    private void Update()   
    {
        GetInput();
    }
    
    private void GetInput()
    {
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    transform.localPosition += transform.forward * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else 
                {
                    transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    transform.localPosition += -transform.forward * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else 
                {
                    transform.localPosition += -transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
            {   
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    transform.localPosition += -transform.right * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else 
                {
                    transform.localPosition += -transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
            {
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    transform.localPosition += transform.right * runSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
                else 
                {
                    transform.localPosition += transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
                }
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
            {
                if (ground == true)
                {
                    rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpPower);
                }
            }
    }   

    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            ground = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
        {
            ground = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error from Unity:

> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable rb of PlayerController has not been assigned.
>
> You probably need to assign the rb variable of the PlayerController script in the inspector.
>
> UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (UnityEngine.Vector3 force, UnityEngine.ForceMode mode) (at :0)
> UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce (UnityEngine.Vector3 force) (at :0)
> PlayerController.GetInput () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:77)
> PlayerController.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs:23)

The player is not jumping

Comment: The error message sounds sensible to me, have you tried "The variable rb of PlayerController has not been assigned. You probably need to assign the rb variable of the PlayerController script in the inspector." ?

Comment: @JensV How can I assign it? Give me code plz

Comment: https://forum.unity.com/threads/rigidbody-and-rb-arent-working.521891/

Comment: `a = b;` <-- assigns b to a.